# Fatal error when using array_diff() function inside of wp_update_nav_menu hook?

Tags: php, functions, menus, hooks, array

I'm attempting to use the PHP native `array_diff()` function inside of a custom function that is attached to the `wp_update_nav_menu` hook:

```
function my_nav_menus( $nav_menu_id ) {
  // .........stuff
  $result = array_diff( $arr1, $arr2 );
  wp_update_nav_menu_object( $nav_menu_id, $result ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', 'my_nav_menus' );
```

Anytime I use `array_diff()` I get an error on menu save saying: `Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string`.

I'm simply trying to capture the result of `array_diff()` and use it in `wp_update_nav_menu_object()`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have arrays of objects, `array_diff` is for comparing arrays of strings.

Comment: Was just about to post an answer to this ... just figured that out. The objects were returned by `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` so I'm looking into using `array_udiff()` instead.